# Vue.js - How to pass parameters to a JavaScript filter function within a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to pass a variable as a parameter to a computed property.

```
computed: {
    dishes() {
      let param = this.cuisine;

      let dishes = this.restaurant.restaurant_items.filter(element => {
        element.param
      });

      return dishes;
    }
},
data(){
    return{
        cuisine:""
    }
}
```

Here as the param I pass a value which is an element of `restaurant_items` array's objects.

eg(:- is_thai)

But this doesn't output me anything. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You want to filter the dishes that match `this.cuisine`? If so you probably want `element => element.param === param` as your filter function

Comment: element.param would be either true or false. I want to filter true from it.

Comment: just do `return element.param` then

Answer (score 0):

Computed properties don't accept parameters. But you can use a method to accomplish the same thing

```
methods: {
    dishes(param) {
        // return whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you actually want to do is:

```
computed: {
  dishes() {
    return this.restaurant.restaurant_items.filter((e) => e[this.cuisine])
  }
}
```

You need to use bracket notation to access object properties via a variable, not dot notation.